# How To calculate nearest location from user?

Tags: iphone

In my application i am having 4 places with its longitude and altitude(Given).Now i want to find the nearest place from user.

So anyone can tell me the solution for it or provide me some source code or demo for this.

Thanks to all

Comment: you havn't accepted answers to any of your questions till now - please change that. from the faq: When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (If you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an CLLocation of the points:

```
CLLocation* locationx = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon];
```

And the compare the points with:

```
double distance = [userposition distanceFromLocation:locationx];
```

Keep the nearest location.

**Edit:**
If you really mean "longitude and altitude" then I dont know how.

Answer (score 1):

just took 10 seconds to ask [google](http://www.google.de/#hl=de&xhr=t&q=distance+calculation+longitude&cp=30&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=distance+calculation+longitude&pbx=1&fp=1121a9849ca33515) and find this, wich describes how to calculate the distance beween two points given latitude and logitude:

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

all you have to do is calculate the distance to all 4 points and choose the lowest one.

**ETDI:** i'm sure you're also given the latitude, otherwise you won't even have specific coordinates. if this wasn't a type and you really have to take the altitude into account, take a look at [this question at google answers](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/326655.html)

Answer (score 0):

picknick describes a native class method.

This is probably going to use the Haversine formula (search the web or stackoverflow for discussions) to measure distances.
In my experience, writing your own Haversine is usually faster than using a system/app-provided one, although this is on Windows where COM overhead can be "problematic" as it were!

The Haversine (and many similar geometry-on-the-Earth) formulae can be found here:

http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm

(this is one of my few bookmarks I go back to for reference on a regular basis!)

Comment: Why over complicate things ;-)

Comment: Giving the full explanation - this is a common question across different languages and environments, so hopefully others will learn. Assuming it is fast enough then your approach would be preferable!

Answer (score -1):

for example user is at x=0,y=0
Calculate the distance by doing : SquareRoot(x2^2 & y2^2)
You will get a distance. Look through all points and compare which distance is the shortest

Comment: this really isn't that easy, as the earth isn't flat - so we have to use the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system ... it's not like calculation distances on a sheet of squared paper. (for small distances, this _might_ work, but it's wrong and we don't know how big what Priyankas distances are)

Comment: This only works for 2d Euclidean space. Not the Earth's surface, and NOT longitude,latitude coordinates. It will only give a reasonable figure at low latitudes and short distances.